# Common convention to name a File class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

In ruby, it's pretty common to see variable named `klass` that holds the name of the class name. Since `class` is a reserved keyword, a misspelled word `klass` serves the purpose.

I'm looking for a similar solution for class that I need to define for a file object.

Obviously

```
class File
end
```

won't work for me because it will start monkey patching the ruby's `File` class which I don't intend.

Is there a name in practice that is commonly used for `File` class? I stumbled upon the idea of using `Fyle` but not sure if this is a great idea and wanted to check with the community :)

**EDIT 1**
Example of my usage.

In my rails app, I have a Product model which has many files. There are other models that also have file associations.

So I want to declare my associations like this

```
class Product
  has_many :files, as: :file_attachable
end

class File # I cannot use `File` because it conflicts with ruby's `File`
  belongs_to :file_attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Could you provide some specific examples as to what you are trying to change or achive?

Comment: @vee I have added an example now. See Edit 1.

Comment: I'm not aware of any commonly used convention for this, but perhaps `ProductFile` would suit your use case?

Comment: @HenrikN since File is polymorphic, calling it ProductFile is not a right choice :)

Comment: @krishworks Aha. `AttachedFile`? `Attachment`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a module namespace. This keeps your File class separate from Ruby's standard File class.

For example:

```
 module Foo
   class File
   end
 end
```

Usage:

```
 f = Foo::File.new
```

For Rails ActiveRecord, you can do:

```
 module Foo
   class File < ActiveRecord::Base
   end
 end
```

Rails will automatically use the table name based on the class that inherits from Base, and *not* based on the module name:

```
Foo::File.table_name #=> "files"
```

You can provide your own `table_name` if you prefer to customize:

```
 module Foo
   class File < ActiveRecord::Base
     self.table_name = "foo_files"
   end
 end
```

Associations work the same way:

```
module Foo
  class User
    has_many :files  # class is Foo::File
  end
end
```

You can provide your own `class_name` if you prefer to customize:

```
module Foo
  class User
     has_many :files, class_name: "Foo::File"
  end
end
```

Comment: namespacing is a good idea. However, now I have to deal with additional overheads in a rails model associations. I mean I no longer can use `has_many :fyles` but have to mention class name and my table name also should be 'foo_files' etc. Is this the standard way?

Comment: I added more info for you. Rails handles all this for you, and also enables you to customize if you prefer.